# Android SearchView Widget - how to display it always expanded and close issue

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I have an activity called `SearchRecipeActivity` which includes: `Toolbar Widget`, `RecyclerView` under it. Inside `Toolbar` I want to add `SearchView Widget` which is always expanded wheneever I enter the activity. This is my first problem. I managed somehow to do it but looks like it does not work as it should.

1. The `SearchView` is focused when I first enter the activity ([X]
       button is highlited as white,
2. When it looses focus and gains it again the `[X]` button is not
       highlited as white but is grey instead - it is not focused?

The second one is connected with when `[X]` button which clears the search text field. When I put some text into `SearchField` it deletes all text as it should, but when the text field is empty, when I click on `[X]` it completely closes the `SearchWidget`. I do not want that as this activity is used only to search. Any way to manage the problem? For example `Twitch` app shows `[X]` button only when the text is inside - to prevent it from closing?

Here is graphical art of my problem :D

[image]

Here are my files:

`search_menu.xml`

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search_widget"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

`SearchActivity.java`

```
public class SearchRecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String TAG = SearchRecipeActivity.class.getSimpleName().toString();

    private CoordinatorLayout searchRecipeCoordinatorLayout;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_recipe);

        // Setting Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting Up CoordinatorLayout
        searchRecipeCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(
                R.id.activity_search_coordinator_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search_widget);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                finish();

                return true;
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```